How to calculate md5sum in EFI shell
I managed to build edk2 and use the created tftp.efi file to load a file from a remote server in the EFI Shell.
I would also like to compute the md5sum of the file and compare the value to check if the correct/undamaged file has been received via tftp.
I could find md5sum related source files in edk2. Is there a way to also build something like the md5sum command in Linux? Or maybe one of the commands of a Pkg already has the functionality, but which?
